# How would you replace only a single character in the middle of text with duplicates?

Tags: regex, notepad++

How would you use the regex in Notepad++ to format replacing a single character that it finds in every line excepts for the duplicate ones in the certain line further?

```
test1:_|TEST:-TEST.|
test2:_|TEST:-TEST.|
test3:_|TEST:-TEST.|
```

As shown in the test code, there are two colons; I'm trying to replace the first colon with each line to a ; and **NOT** the second one found; the result of me doing the regex should equal to this:

```
test1;_|TEST:-TEST.|
test2;_|TEST:-TEST.|
test3;_|TEST:-TEST.|
```

Comment: I don't know how regex on notepad worls, but something like this could be possible: .*?(:).*    Meaning: consume everything non-greedy until you hit a colon, select the colon and consume the rest

Comment: `As shown in the test code, there are two colons` I don't see code, but if you're talking about the highlighted string, I see six colons. Maybe you miscounted .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe this expression,

```
(\w+)\s*(?::)(\s*_\s*\|\s*\w+\s*:\s*-\w+\.\|)
```

with a replacement of `$1;$2` might work.

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/xBrFZ6/1/)

Or with less boundaries, this expression:

```
([^:]+):(.*)
```

with the same replace.

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/rM9xKR/1/)

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?\K:`
- Replace with: `;`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .+?       # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
  :         # colon
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: I had this answer in my head too.♥♥♥♥

Answer (score 0):

It's done like this

Find `(?m)^[^:\r\n]*\K:`
Replace `;`

https://regex101.com/r/rT1vG9/1